# In DDPM, why is "forward posterior" needed?

Tags: diffusion-models

From [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239):

[image]

But what's the point of $q(x_t\mid x_t, x_0)$? Right before that, we already have:

[image]

So we already know what $q(x_t\mid x_0)$ is for any $t$.

My questions:

- What's the point of showing (6)? (It is used throughout rest of formulas, but it could just depend on $x_0$ everywhere, no? Even during sampling it could just use $\hat{x_0}$)
- Are (6) and (4) equivalent somehow?

Comment: Can you please include the name and link to the paper in your post?

Comment: @nbro Will do - it's just the original DDPM paper. https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239